# Is any other way to declare global variables without using static keyword in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I declare global variables in MVC application without using static ?

I am currently following the static approach and it is causing issues when the application is logged in from different users at the same time.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In a web based environment, it is generally not a good idea this approach. You can use middleware but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: global variables are usually not a good practice.

Comment: Global variables will cause issues with concurrent users whether you use `static` or not. What's the problem you're trying to solve by using global variables?

Comment: You can store values in Session.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe are there any server variable which scope is limited to application only ?

Comment: I know in Java web (or, Vaadin, anyway. Not sure if it's a general thing), global statics are somehow treated as per-session, as if every user has his own "program" running. Not sure how that's handled in asp.net though.

Comment: @Nyerguds In ASP.NET they are shared across the entire application...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, when I found out about that particular oddity it kind of horrified me, to be honest. That's just _not_ how statics are supposed to work...

Comment: It has its use cases @Nyerguds

Comment: You seem to be asking for Application variables, but you would probably end up with the same problem as with your current static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make them *global per user*, I would suggest to use the `Session` context to save the variables to. This is not really on a user level, since a user can log in multiple times, but usually this suits better in my experience.

I usually have something like this:

```
public string Prop
{
    get
    {
        return (string)Session["Prop"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["Prop"] = value;
    }
}
```

This will make accessing the property very easy and consistent.

Comment: if we want to use the list in it ?is it suitable ?

Comment: Yes, for what I know, any data type is allowed.

Comment: but what if data is large ?

Comment: Not a real problem. You have to keep in mind that 100 users can allocate quite some memory.

Comment: Hi Patrick thank you for your help I have implemented the session approach and I am able to access values but the application stops after few seconds and I get the error code of 0 in my ajax call.
can you please help me with it?

Comment: Unless you have some code and explanation, it will be hard to answer. Please ask a new question with all details necessary to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to session you can also use application object. Also you can store variables in cache.